On Luzin's generalization of Egoroff's Theorem: the case of domain of infinite measure
According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem#CITEREFSaks1937 Luzin's generalization of Egoroff's Theorem reads as follows: If a measurable set A is the union of a sequence of measurable sets of finite $\mu$-measure, and $(f_n)$ is a given sequence of (real) measurable functions on some measure space (X,Σ,μ), such that $(f_n)$ converges $μ$-almost everywhere on $A$ to a limit (real) function $f$, then $A$ can be expressed as the union of a sequence of measurable sets $H$, $A_1$, $A_2$,... such that $\mu(H)=0$ and ($f_n$) converges to $f$ uniformly on each set $A_k$. More precisely, the idea of the proof is suppose to be to first consider the case when $\mu(A)<+\infty$ and to inductively define sets $(A_k)$ in such a way that it holds that:
$$\lambda(A\backslash\cup_{i=1}^{m}A_i)\leq{1\over{m}}.$$
My question is: how does one actually defines sets $(A_k)$ and how does one actually proves the assertion of this generalized version of Egoroff's Theorem? Is the assertion here that we can get $\lambda(A\backslash\cup_{i=1}^{m}A_i)\leq{1\over{m}}$ even in the case when $\mu(A)=+\infty$? This does not sound likely true to me.
My remarks are as follows:
Remark1. The point here is that we allow the case when $\mu(A)=+\infty$. Notice that, if $\mu(A)=+\infty$, then it can not be true that $\mu(A_k)<+\infty$ for every $k\in N$, since
this would imply $\mu(A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{m}\mu(A_i)+\mu(A\backslash\cup_{i=1}^{m}A_i)<+\infty$.
Remark2. If $\mu(A)<+\infty$, then $\mu(A_k)<+\infty$, and the standard proof of Egoroff's Theorem applies, which was already established in previous questions, see, for instance:
if a function sequence converges a.e, then it uniformly converges a.e
Remark3.  I am satisfied with the consideration of the case when $A\subseteq{\bf R}$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\mu=\lambda$.
Remark4. As I understand the statement of this version of Egoroff's Theorem, the point is to choose sets $A_k$ as large as possible (in terms of the measure of $A_k$). We can certainly achieve (by a direct application of the standard Egoroff's Theorem on the domain of finite measure, see, for example
Question on Egoroff-like theorem
) uniform convergence on sets $C_k$ of small measure, and decompose $A$ as $A=\cup_{k=1}^{+\infty}C_k\cup H_0$, where $\mu(C_k)<+\infty$ and $\mu(H_0)=0$, but that is not the point here in my opinion.
Remark5. This version of Egoroff's Theorem is mentioned in textbook
Saks, Stanisław (1937), Theory of the Integral, Monografie Matematyczne, vol. 7, translated by Young, L. C., with two additional notes by Stefan Banach (2nd ed.), Warszawa-Lwów: G.E. Stechert & Co., pp. VI+347, JFM 63.0183.05, Zbl 0017.30004 (available at the Polish Virtual Library of Science).
http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-42a56b61-37f4-4c6b-a42b-ea95a98e407a
in Chapter I, on page 19, but I was not able to find this version mentioned elsewhere.
Remark6. We are not claiming here that sets $(A_k)$ are pairwise disjoint (or that the measure of the intersection $A_i\cap A_j$ is zero for $i\neq j$).
Remark7. The point of this version of Egoroff's Theorem is that it holds on the domain $A$ of infinite measure, and we do not need to impose additional conditions of the sequence $(f_n)$, such as the condition $|f_n|\leq g$ (almost everywhere on $A$), where $g\in {\rm L}^1(A)$, which was already discussed in questions like the following one:
Omitting the hypotheses of finiteness of the measure in Egorov theorem
